# Add certain mysql rows together

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
Article ID, Views, Date
11,     55,   2013-01-01
12,     341,  2013-01-01
11,     432,  2013-01-02
```

And I want to create a new table that only has the sums for each article in the Views field (i.e.:)

```
Article ID, Views
11, 487
12, 341
```

Do I have to write a script that does each one individually or is there a mysql statement for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Insert into Table2 (`Article Id`, Views)
Select `Article ID`, SUM(Views)
FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY `Article ID`;
```

**[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00937/1)**

Comment: thanks, I combined that with a CREATE ... AS SELECT and it worked. THanks

Answer (score 0):

You do that with one simple query

```
INSERT INTO SumTable (ArticleId, Views) 
SELECT ArticleId, SUM(Views) FROM SourceTable GROUP BY ArticleId
```

If you want to also create a new table you can combine CREATE and SELECT as described here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE SumTable SELECT ArticleId, SUM(Views) FROM SourceTable GROUP BY ArticleId
```